# Firebase resource location different in emulator (from CLI) and project GUI

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a project that's been using firebase storage, auth, and firestore for quite some time, and I'm now adding functions for the first time.

I've added an emulator and functions to the codebase by running both `firebase init emulator` and `firebase init functions` in my project directory, and it's all running fine.

But I noticed the resource location, `us-central1`, does not match my project's resource location, `eur3/europe-west`.

In the attached screenshot you can see from my terminal that the current project is set to `europe/west`, but the function is initialised int he emulator from `us-central1`. As far as I understand it, this can cause quite serious performance problems.

Is this only the case for emulators? Or is there a way I can make sure that when my functions are actually hosted in firebase that they will be in the correct resource location?

[image]

Comment: Seems relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/anqeze/function_emulator_not_using_configured_region/epwrcml/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to use the default region, you can declare the region when you write your functions:

```
exports.exampleFunction = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.redirect("https://www.google.com");
});
```

Comment: is there no way doing this with environment variables?